# Probability interval givem symmetric difference and the union of two events

Tags: probability

> The events $E$, $F$ and $P$ satisfy the constraints $(E \triangle F) = .7$, $P (E ∪ F) = .8$.
>
> - (A.) Calculate $P (E ∩ F)$, making sure that is uniquely determined.
> - (B.) Determine the range of possible values of $P (E)$.
> - (C.) There may be independent $E,F$ events satisfying the constraints?

So I have done (A.) $P (E ∩ F) = .1$ and $P(E)+P(F)=.9$

At this point, I think that for (B.) $P(E)$ should be $<.9$ but I can't find the low limit.

For point (C.) I know that $P (E ∩ F)=P(E)P(F)$ if independent events. So I think I have to replace it on $P (E ∪ F)=P(E)+P(F)-P (E ∩ F)$ and see if the values ould exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(B)$, observe that
$$
P(E) \geq P(E \cap F) = 0.1
$$
Also observe that you have over estimated the upper bound since
$$
P(E) \leq P(E \cup F) = 0.8
$$
For $(C)$, if exist, then
$$
\begin{cases}
P(E) \cdot P(F) = 0.1 \\
P(E) + P(F) = 0.9
\end{cases}
$$
Solving these equations, we can obtain one solution as
$$
P(E) = \frac{0.9 + \sqrt{0.41}}{2},\quad P(F) = \frac{0.9 - \sqrt{0.41}}{2} \tag{$1$}
$$
One example achieving these probabilities is a uniform random variable $X$ on $[0, 1]$. Let $E$ be the event that $\{X \leq \frac{0.9 + \sqrt{0.41}}{2}\}$ and $F$ be the event that $\{0.8 \geq X \geq \frac{0.7 + \sqrt{0.41}}{2}\}$. Then the probability of $E$ and $F$ satisfy $(1)$ and the conditions in the question.